# Calling methods on activity events

Tags: android

I am writing a simple Android library. I have a couple of methods that I would like executed when certain activity events happen - like after activity got loaded or when the activity gets paused.

One way I could think of was to create a class that extends activity, and write my methods there, and then have "target" activities extend that class. This was all methods get called

But if the end user is extending some other activity already, this method won't work. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you need only provide support back to API 14 or higher, you might be able to make use of the application level activity lifecycle callbacks - see the [`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) interface for details.

To make use of this you need to register an instance of this interface with an `Application` instance, using the [`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) method. One way to get that would be to have the developer using your library initialise your library by passing their `Application` instance to it. This is what I do in an SDK that I maintain, and it seems to work nicely.